# Why Capybara cant find css?

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I try to write simple feature spec, but I dont understand Capybara behavior. So, I have that code:

```
> parent.class
=> Capybara::Node::Element
> parent.find(:css, 'button.remove-arrow')
=> Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "button.remove-arrow"
from /Users/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
```

but when i try to do call via web-driver:

```
> parent.native.find(:css, 'button.remove-arrow')
```

it return me right answer

```
=> [#<Capybara::Poltergeist::Node tag="button" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/FORM[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/BUTTON[1]">]
```

what I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is that the node isn't actually visible on the page, which Capybara takes into account, but the driver doesn't.  If

```
parent.find(:css, 'button.remove-arrow', visible: :false)
```

finds the element it would confirm that visibility is indeed the difference.  If not then the actual HTML/CSS would be needed to know why.

Comment: lemme check Thomas

Comment: @vear You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer (checkmark on left) if it helped you so the questions gets marked as answered